# Overriding helper method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I have following line in my `rails helper`.

```
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

But I want to modify it to

```
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

But I don't want to modify it for every tests inside `spec` folder. I just want to apply it to all the tests inside `spec/requests` folder.
How can I do it ?

Comment: Why not to have 2 separate test_helper.rb files?

Comment: I don't know. Can you clear a little bit. Means how ?

Comment: Basically you create two files such as following: test_helper.rb and test_helper_transactional.rb then require one of them that you need in a test.

Comment: Actually the line mentioned above is present in the code from very long time. I have used it at many places, so I can't relocate it in another file and use that instead. And rails_helper is required everywhere in the domain by default, so I can't change that without much effort. I just want to override this line whenever I want, even though the rails_helper is required in that file.

Comment: each test file has **require 'test_helper'** at the very top. In case of different configuration use a modified clone of test_helper.rb as advised above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a bit more research, it looks like you need to use the DatabaseCleaner gem https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner.  In your rails helper, you would add this:

```
require 'database_cleaner'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before type: :request do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.after type: :request  do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

This will set you up so that request specs will use the truncation strategy (removing all data from the database) and everything but request specs use transactions (rollback all changes from runnning scenario).

Comment: It's not working. I'm putting my file in `spec/requests/api/v1` folder. Does it matter ?

Comment: do you have `require rails_helper` and  `RSpec.describe "Your Spec Name Here", :type => :request do` at the top of your request specs?

Comment: I got my answer. Actually I was seeding before running the spec and as after each example, only the changes made during the example are rolle back, my seeded data isn't being deleted as  I did it outside the test environment. So, basically I don't need to reconfigure my rails_helper. But, thanks for helping me.